# Backward compatibility issues with SparkML Model migration from scala 2.11 to scala 2.12

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

We're migrating our MLpipeline from Spark 2.4(scala 2.11.11) to Spark 3.3.0(scala 2.12.17) we were not able to read the existing MLModel with spark 3.
This is because scala won’t support BC with major release upgrade.
Seems this is not a Spark issue, As I was able to load the PipelineModel.
The issue that I am facing now is we're storing a case class as binary object which is having Map datatype in scala 2.11.11 and trying to read that object file back with scala 2.12.17.
While doing that I am getting the below exception,

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7746713615561179240, local class serialVersionUID = -7992135791595275193
```

Sample case class(just adding one column here):
case class LearningModelOutput(
transformerState: Map[String, Any])

The object that we're storing is like

```
0 = {Tuple2@8285} (targetColumn,)
1 = {Tuple2@8286} (consideredColumns,[Ljava.lang.String;@35b49c11)
2 = {Tuple2@8287} (schema,StructType(StructField(col1,IntegerType,true), StructField(col2,LongType,true
3 = {Tuple2@8288} (transformerStages,Map())
```

When trying to read this objectfile using spark.sparkcontext.objectfileMap[String, Any]
getting the above mentioned serialization error.

Comment: I think your issue has more to do with `json4s` and the choices you made while serialising the model and less to do with any of the Spark stuff.

Comment: Json4s is something I tried which didn't work. I have updated the question to be clear.
But Seems this is not a Spark issue, As I was able to load the PipelineModel.

The issue that I am facing now is we're storing a case class as binary object which is having Map datatype in scala 2.11 and trying to read that object file.
While doing that I am getting the below exception,
"java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7746713615561179240, local class serialVersionUID = -7992135791595275193"

Comment: If you are saving binary objects, then you pretty much need to use exact same implementation. You will have to look at the original class and the new one to see whether you it can work with a data only export. If not then, define your custom intermediate class to bridge the gap. You can create an exporter where you use the original version to deserialise, then export as only data or your bridge class. then use the bridge class to read it.

Comment: I am just storing the model related properties which is of type Map[String,Any] as rdd.saveAsObjectFile("path") using scala 2.11. Cannot read that back using scala 2.12.. The Map is having value of type String, StructField & StructType.

Comment: This is simple data. Why are you even saving this as binary ? You can properly serialize this data as Json and save to the file. Just use original Spark version to load it, then properly export it as Json data.